# I can't input the data into my table using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I can't input the data into my MySQL table using this script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
include '../scripts/test_ses.php';
include 'connection.php';
$date = date("Y-m-d");   
/* Set our params */
$id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$active = 1;
$sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_Holiday (Status, Active, DateOfChange) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE idRequest =$id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

/* Bind our params */
$stmt->bind_param('iisi', $status, $active, $date, $id);

/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* Close the statement */
$stmt->close();
?>
```

The data of the variables $id, $status is set by a form is there any way  to display the php error of the script by alerting it on the form page over ajax ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as jQuery?

Comment: INSERT shouldn't be used with a WHERE clause, are you trying to UPDATE?

Comment: may be u need an update query

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new rows. It makes no sense to have a `WHERE` clause, since that refers to existing rows. If you want to change an existing row, you should use `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `$id` and `WHERE` they are used for update or delete a row, in your case insert use below query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_Holiday 
             (Status, Active, DateOfChange) VALUES 
             (?, ?, ?)";
```

or if you wanted to update you need to use below query

```
$sql = "UPDATE TBL_Holiday SET 
           Status= ?,
           Active= ?,
           DateOfChange= ? 
        WHERE idRequest = ?";


/* Bind our params */
$stmt->bind_param('iisi', $status, $active, $date, $id);
```

Comment: It's still not valid to have a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement

Comment: Now you're not doing anything with the `$id` input.

Answer (score 1):

by having its id.. make the update operation..

```
$sql = "UPDATE TBL_Holiday SET Status='$status', Active='$active', DateOfChange='$date' WHERE idRequest =$id";
```

otherwise.. make insert by ..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_Holiday (Status, Active, DateOfChange) VALUES ('$status', '$active', '$date')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using insert you need to use Update query if you need to use condition while. So your condition will be something like this,

```
$sql = "UPDATE  TBL_Holiday SET Status= ?,Active= ?,DateOfChange=? WHERE idRequest =$id";
```

Answer (score 1):

### You're mixing an INSERT statement with an UPDATE statement

An insert statement is on the form:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...);
```

- Where you're creating a new record which is not associated with any other existing rows using a `where` clause, i.e. you're suppose to skip that part.

Meanwhile an update statement is on the form:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

- Where you do indeed wish to associate your update with some specific row by using a `where` clause, to indicate which row is to be updated.

Not my favorite sources but you can take a look at [insert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and [update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Answer (score 0):

***This is the working code:***

```
<?php
    /* Set our params */
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $active = 1;

    /*Create executed SQL*/
    $sql = "UPDATE TBL_Holiday SET 
            Status= ?, 
            Active =?, 
            DateOfChange =?  
            WHERE idRequest = ?";

    /*Prepare SQL connection*/   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    /* Bind our params */
    $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $status, $active, $date, $id);

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Close the statement */
    $stmt->close();
?>
```